# Java Generics initialization of child class in base class

Tags: java, generics

I'm pretty new to java and not particularly sure how to initialize a generic type / child class from the 'base' class.
Essentially I have a bunch of classes that extend the abstract class `BaseClass` that need to be initialized and added to the `instance` Map if a key is not present.
The child class is re-used multiple times but is dynamically created based on the `key` parameter.

I would like to avoid reflection and don't mind changing the template if it's not 'the Java way'.
What I currently have:

```java
public abstract class BaseClass<T> {
    protected Map<String, T> instance = new HashMap<String, T>();

    public T Get(String key) {
        if (this.instance.containsKey(key)) {
            return this.instance.get(key);
        } 
        T item = new T(key); // Obviously this line errors but you get the idea
        instance.put(key, item);
        return item;
    }
}

// Example top class which extends my base class
public class TopClass extends BaseClass<TopClass> {
    public TopClass(String key) {
        // Do unique initialization stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you plan to link the `key` string to an actual subclass? (there will be multiple subclasses)

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? I can't tell if you want a factory or a multiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since generic types are erased at runtime, you cannot do this. You can instead use a Class variable as follows:

```
public T Get(Class<T> clazz, String key) throws Exception {
    if (this.instance.containsKey(key)) {
        return this.instance.get(key);
    } 
    T item = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class).newInstance(key);
    instance.put(key, item);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: I like this way, reflection is only used when a new item needs to be initialized and passing the class in is easy.

Answer (score 1):

I have another approach to this.

Have an interface MyInterface.

```
   public interface MyIinterface{
      public void doSomething();
   }
```

Create an many implementations of this interface.

```
@Component
public class MyImplementation1 implements MyInterface{

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){

    }
}
```

Use spring core jars in the dependency.

Annotate all the implementations with @Component.

```
@Component
public class MyImplementation1 implements MyInterface{
.
.
```

Have a method in some Util class that will get you the implementation based on a string key.

```
public static MyInterface getImplementation(String name){

  ApplicationContext context;
  return context.getBeanByName(name);

}
```